# Nuget: Is there a transformation token available to get the location of the package tools folder?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I am trying to use Nuget to distribute a ms build .targets file. I need to modify some elements of the file to include the installed path of a few assemblies. For that I would like to use the tools folder. I am having a hard time finding the token (if it exists) to do the replacement. Has anyone encountered this problem or know of a workaround?

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to go the PowerShell route to get this done, as no transform exists AFAIK. The init.ps1 file can process some parameters provided by the NuGet VSIX.

Simply add the following to the top of the init.ps1 file and use the **$installPath** variable in your scripts that modify the file content.

> param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

Check [here](https://github.com/myget/NuGetPackages/blob/master/NuSpec/tools/init.ps1) for an example usage.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was afraid that was the answer. I just wanted to make sure before i went that route. I will give it a try in a few.